# Java Repository и Facade чем они отличаются?

Tags: java, android

Вот пишу проект и я совсем запутался.
Когда использовать `Repository pattern`  когда `Facade pattern` ?Ведь по сути оба скрывают реализацию того или иного метода.Буду благодарен за небольшие примеры

Comment: Из слов все паттерны использующие инкапсуляцию одинаковы?) На самом деле у обоих паттернов совершенно другая цель и они абсолютно разные. Вкратце фасад поможет предоставить понятные интерфейсы для сложных систем, на практике это структурная обёртка(structure wrapper), а вот Repository это что-то вроде Data-Mapper и его задача отдать понятный тип данных из сложной струкьуры данных. отличие еще в том, что репозиторий занимается преобразованием данных и работаем с дата слоем, а фасад представляет только интерфейсы обернутой системы и может ничего не знать про data. В Android оба очень популярны

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei прошу пример небольшой )и как ответ оформите чтоб я его выбрал )

Comment: на самом деле хороший вопрос, его бы оформить достойно, ведь действительно сейчас в Android оба паттерна часто встречаются

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фасад — структурный шаблон проектирования, позволяющий скрыть сложность системы путём сведения всех возможных внешних вызовов к одному объекту, делегирующему их соответствующим объектам системы.

Пример из жизни: Как вы включаете компьютер? Нажимаю на кнопку включения, скажете вы. Это то, во что вы верите, потому что вы используете простой интерфейс, который компьютер предоставляет для доступа снаружи. Внутри же должно произойти гораздо больше вещей. Этот простой интерфейс для сложной подсистемы называется фасадом.[клик](https://tproger.ru/translations/design-patterns-simple-words-2/#25)

Репозиторий - это слой абстракции, инкапсулирующий в себе всё, что относится к способу хранения данных. Назначение: Разделение бизнес-логики от деталей реализации слоя доступа к данным.[клик](https://gist.github.com/maestrow/594fd9aee859c809b043)