# Чистая архитектура Repository это и есть Gatewqay?

Tags: java, android, mvp

Добрый день смотрю разные схемы `mvp + clean` ,так вот в одной из этих реализаций видел некую особеннось где была схема `Repository/Gateway -> converter->api...`
так вот я не понел в каком случае в `interactor` использовать `repository` а в каких `gateway`?

Comment: Это разные паттерны, часто вижу как Репозиторий используют как Gateway. Clean больше подходит Gateway. Repository это Data-Mapper, a Gateway это Wrapper, его задача предоставить вам простой интерфей из сложных систем. Я недавно писал разницу Repository != Facade. Не могу найти, видимо тоже комментарий был.

Comment: тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829282/java-repository-%D0%B8-facade-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F/829621#829621

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei . facade repository тоже был мой вопрос ))))) ооп головного мозга в андроиде у меня )

Comment: @ShevchykVitalii да вот спасибо. так вот Gateway ну ооочень схож паттерн с Facade, просто у них контекст разный. фасад больше для работы с класмми внутри системы, а вот Gateway дает простой интерфейс из разных систем. Поэтому в Android Repository или делают чистым Gateway или как обычно это какаой-то гибрид. Ну да, они очень схожи, вангую вопрос Gateway == Facade = ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei ахахах )))точно ))))))Думаю всеже надо как то эти темы описать по хорошему а то бредятина кака ято )